# How to maintain iMac dock settings on network computer?

Tags: mac, dock

So I use this school iMac computer often, and it requires me to log into the school's network system. I like my dock icons large and magnified whenever I hover the mouse over them, so I changed these settings; these dock settings, however, reset every time I log out, and so I have to re-enable them every time I log back in. Is there a way to keep these settings unchanged after logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your school enabled Guest-account mode, which lets anyone login and use the computer, but then restores the account to as new upon logoff.  If that's the situation, you'll need to contact school IT and inquire about getting your own account.

If you're able to save a file between logins, you can create the following script and run it to reset to your preferences more quickly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dock magnification
defaults write com.apple.dock magnification -bool true

# Icon size of magnified Dock items
defaults write com.apple.dock largesize -int 96

# Restart the Dock
killall Dock
```

Replace the '96' with the size in pixels that suits your prefs.